# Using expression for limit in Neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My cypher query is

```
start item= node:jobSearch ("title:Job*") WITH collect(item) as items limit 10  RETURN items as job union start item2= node:jobSearch ("title:Job*") WITH collect(item2) as item2s , count(item2) as paths  match (job1:Job)-[relation]-(relationNode)  where 
(relationNode.name IN ['java','Dance','Programming'] OR relation.duration IN 
['java','Dance','Programming']) AND  NOT (job1 IN item2s) AND paths < 10   RETURN  job1  as job limit 8
```

where I have used limit 8 in above query  , I want to use 10 - paths .
How can i use this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it would seem that you should be able to do this with an expression in the limit clause, or perhaps by computing the right integer in your last `WITH` statement, (e.g. `WITH (10-paths) as resultCount (...) limit resultCount`) but I tested this and it won't work.

Just for kicks, I looked into the neo4j source code to see if I was missing something.  [In this source file](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3f6ea4df68a7c56bc3fa91a0141393b103f81276/community/cypher/cypher-compiler-2.2/src/main/scala/org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v2_2/parser/Clauses.scala) you can see some of the rules for clauses and parsing of the cypher language itself.

The bad news is that the `LIMIT` expression expects either an unsigned integer literal, or a parameter.   So basically you can't do what you're asking to do, unless you compute `(10-paths)` in a separate query, then put into this query a `{resultCount}` parameter, and then give it that pre-computed value.   That would probably be a lot of work for not much value.

On the upside, unless your results are really monstrously huge, it's probably easiest to just `LIMIT 10` and include the integer `paths` in your result set so that the code that consumes these results knows to ignore any more results than that.